# How to deploy a package built with Visual Studio 2017 to sql Server 2008?

Tags: ssis, visual-studio-2017

I have built an SSIS project on Visual Studio 2017, I would like to deploy the packages to a sql server 2008 environment.

Deployment must be done by file system.

Have you any solutions ? Or is it not possible ?

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: In the title you have SQL Server 2008, in the body SQL Server 2012: which?

Comment: You're right, it was not understandable.